Can I build WebAssembly from rust and cargo with target bundler and use it in react CRA?
I want to build WebAssembly using rust, cargo and build with wasm-pack:
wasm-pack build --target bundler
npm link
In my react apps (typescript):
npm link example-modules_wasm
Then, I import function from modules example-modules_wasm. but it doesn't work.
Can I build WebAssembly and use it in the react apps without any bundler webpack, vite,...?
I can work well when I build with --target web. but I want to try with target bundler.
thanks for help.
